# Как удалить из коллекции все отрицательные числа?

Tags: java, коллекции, java-stream

Можно это сделать используя `java.util.stream`?
Пытался сделать это обычным способом, но не получается, думаю из-за сдвига после `remove()`.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(-1);
    list.add(-2);
    list.add(-3);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(1);

    for(int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++) {
        if(list.get(i) < 0) 
            list.remove(i);
    }
```

Comment: Нельзя идти по массиву и проводить с ним манипуляции! Создайте новый массив и добавляйте туда элементы, удовлетворяющие условию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [Эникейщик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/282277/%D0%AD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA):

> Нельзя идти по массиву и проводить с ним манипуляции! Создайте новый
>   массив и добавляйте туда элементы, удовлетворяющие условию.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(-1,-2,-3,5,4,2));

        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++) 
            if(list.get(i) > 0)
                list2.add(list.get(i));
```

Comment: Если во время `for`, влетит новый элемент, получим в лоб `ConcurrentModificationException` - решение не из лучших.

Comment: @And и что делать? Есть способы решения проблемы кроме синхр. коллекции?

Answer (score 11):

В `Java 8` появился специальный метод, для удаления элементов коллекции, которые соответствуют заданному предикату:

```
list.removeIf(value -> value < 0);
```

P.S и не требуется создавать новую коллекцию.

Answer (score 5):

Вот так можно создать новую коллекцию с только положительными числами с помощью стримов.

```
list = list.stream()
           .filter(s -> s > 0)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```